# Response Code From Google comes in wrong format upon on first sign in using Oauth 2.0 Authentication

Tags: google-signin, google-oauth, social-authentication

Response Code received after signing on to google for first time.

[http://localhost:8080/?state=trueprompt%3Dconsent&code=4%2FjlCxJC7rg57nOG7w-0MP4M1BuQ7cbI4GLCNofMzPeQQ#][1]

Below given is the code i am using

```
GoogleConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new GoogleConnectionFactory("CLIENT_ID","CLIENT_SECRET");
        System.out.println(connectionFactory.getScope());
        connectionFactory.generateState();
        OAuth2Operations oauthoperations =connectionFactory.getOAuthOperations();
        OAuth2Parameters params = new OAuth2Parameters();
        params.setRedirectUri("http://localhost:8080");
        params.setScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile");
        params.setState("true");
        String authorizeUrl = oauthoperations.buildAuthenticateUrl(GrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE,params);
```

After receving the authorizeUrl i am pasting that directly on to the browser, then it takes me to google signin page. After signing in it redirects back to call-back url with the code parameter value, which is mentioned at the very first link.

But that response code is not working for getting the Access Token. when i again copy paste the same login url on to brwoser it responds with a different response code which is mentioned below. This time as i am already logged i don't have to login in again and it responds with a different responds code which is working fine and i am able to get the AccessToken. The difference between first and second response code is that in first it responds with 4% where as in second it comes with 4/.

http://localhost:8080/?state=true&code=4/0Y9NMh9fYAr3kfy3r1por3Py1LCdbOsIUz3fwdv78gc#

```
        AccessGrant accessGrant = oauthoperations.exchangeForAccess("AUTHORIZATION_CODE", "http://localhost:8080",null );
        Connection<Google> connection = connectionFactory.createConnection(accessGrant);
        System.out.println(connection.getDisplayName());
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: @CBroe can you help me out on this??

Comment: Can anyone help with this bug